# why new Function() return comments /**/ in arguments?

Tags: javascript, node.js

in chrome 47 and nodejs v0.12

`new Function('myArg','return "my function body";')`

gives the following results :

```
function anonymous(myArg /**/) {
  return "my function body"
}
```

why is there comments /**/ in the function arguments ?

Comment: They needed it to fix the arguments parser for ES6. Wait, I'll dig up the bug discussion

Comment: [Here's](https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/v8natives.js#1846) the short explanation (as comment) in the source of the V8 engine: _"If the formal parameters include an unbalanced block comment, the function must be rejected. Since JavaScript does not allow nested comments we can include a trailing block comment to catch this."_

Comment: So, it's just a way of making `'myArg /*'` not throw an error? or what.

Comment: @KevinB yes it seems to be the reason. i'm wondering why it don't throw an error in case you put an unblanced comment instead of allowing it and fixing it with this workaround

Comment: Definitely seems a bit strange to me. akin to fixing a broken conditional with `if (foo === bar || true)`. I can't find any explanation of why it was added.

Comment: @KevinB not sure where that's from but surely `&& true` or `|| false`?

Comment: depends on whether you want it to always fail or always succeed. :) the point is who knows.

Comment: @KevinB I'm thinking you're looking at this backwards - it's a way of making `"myArg /*"` *throw* an error. My reading of it is that rather than parsing comments as they go and checking if it's balanced, they insert another comment, so it will translate to `function anonymous(myArg /*/**/)` which will then fail compilation because it looks like a nested comment. Bit of a hack, but works.

Comment: @CupawnTae ```function anonymous(myArg /*/**/)``` do not throw any error

Comment: Ah, i think i see the confusion. `new Function('myArg /*','return "my function body";')` doesn't fail compilation, which is why i made it always succeed instead of fail.

Comment: @fadomire that's an interesting point - I was just going on how I read the comments in the source "since JavaScript does not allow nested comments we can include a trailing block comment to catch this"

Comment: Ah, I was actually refering to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=755821 - seems Firefox is going to do the same

Comment: @KevinB turns out it *is* to cause errors, not resolve errors, but it is indeed a particularly odd way of doing it. The argument list itself doesn't cause an error, but if you have a `*/` in the body of the function, it will no longer match a corresponding `/*` in the argument list, and *that* will now throw a syntax error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As seen in the following [Chromium issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=331655), this is a workaround to remedy an edge case involving unbalanced block comments. As described in the [V8 source code](https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/v8natives.js#1846):

```
function NewFunctionString(arguments, function_token) {
  var n = arguments.length;
  var p = '';
  if (n > 1) {
    p = ToString(arguments[0]);
    for (var i = 1; i < n - 1; i++) {
      p += ',' + ToString(arguments[i]);
    }
    // If the formal parameters string include ) - an illegal
    // character - it may make the combined function expression
    // compile. We avoid this problem by checking for this early on.
    if (%_CallFunction(p, ')', StringIndexOfJS) != -1) {
      throw MakeSyntaxError('paren_in_arg_string', []);
    }
    // If the formal parameters include an unbalanced block comment, the
    // function must be rejected. Since JavaScript does not allow nested
    // comments we can include a trailing block comment to catch this.
    p += '\n/' + '**/';
  }
  var body = (n > 0) ? ToString(arguments[n - 1]) : '';
  return '(' + function_token + '(' + p + ') {\n' + body + '\n})';
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This was originally added to catch cases like the following and throw an error:

```
Function("/*", "*/){alert('bad');")
```

This should result in a syntax error, but before they added the additional `/**/`, it would be translated to:

```
function anonymous(/*) {
  */){alert('bad');
}
```

Which is equivalent to

```
function anonymous(/*...*/) {
  alert('bad');
}
```

And hence no syntax error. After the change, with the extra comment this now becomes:

```
function anonymous(/*/**/) {
  */){alert('bad');
}
```

which correctly gives a syntax error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token *(…)
```

[Source revision](https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/detail?r=13882&path=/trunk/src/v8natives.js) and [original bug report](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2470).